# How to capture video from IP camera using java?

Tags: java, video-capture

here i'm trying to execute a code found with google for capturing video from an IP Camera.
i use NetBeans 7.1

link for complete code here : [http://blog.950buy.com/article/capture-video-from-ip-camera-using-jmf/][1]

I have two lines in red and i don't understand why.
please could comeone check errors in these lines:

```
....
public String jpgURL=”http://10.0.0.81/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=1024×768″;
public String mjpgURL=”http://10.0.0.81/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=1024×768″;
....
```

My NetBeans 7.1 says there is illegal character \8221

Thank you
PS : The whole code is too big to put here.

Comment: OK i found my error, it was stupi i just forget to put correctly "" but still when i launch the code, i have a blank window.

Comment: *"but still when i launch the code, i have a blank window."*  1) Mark one of the answers correct.  2) Ask a new question.  3) Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  People usually won't follow links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

excerpt from this [site](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/compileerrormessages.html)

> You used Unicode 8220 (aka \u291c, 0x291c, “, left quote) or 8821 (aka
>   \u291d, 0x291d, ”, right quote) instead of a simple 34 (aka \u0022,
>   0x22, ") that Java requires. This probably resulted from using a word
>   processor like MS Word instead of a text processor or IDE to compose
>   your Java source which converts "s into “ and ”.

Comment: Yes thank you i know my mistake. But actually i'm using an IP camera with an address like :

Comment: es thank you i know my mistake. But actually i'm using an IP camera with an address like : http://99.4.100.100/index1.htm of course this address is not for my real web cam, my question is when i put this address at line public String jpgURL=”http://10.0.0.81/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=1024×768″;
public String mjpgURL=”http://10.0.0.81/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=1024×768″;
I always have a blank window, thank you

Comment: If you have another question, file another question. The problem for this question is identified.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String jpgURL=”h
                     ^---not a real quote
```

You've got the same quote-type on both lines, and they're not the type of quote needed by java to treat the contents as a string.